# Why picture rotates automatically while doing image trace

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, image-trace

I wanted to practice some image tracing and I wanted to adjust some colors etc. But when I try to edit an original photo in Photoshop, the image opens as rotated, and after the changes it also opens as rotated at AI as well.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Some cameras record the orientation of the device when a photo is taken, and add an orientation flag in the file metadata, which software like Photoshop will respect when opening the file. It should (in practice) rotate the image to the correct orientation that the photograph was taken in.

If you don't want that, you can turn off this behaviour in the preferences

[image]

There's no equivalent setting in Illustrator, as far as I'm aware. You may have to manually rotate the image if it opens in the wrong orientation.